# Expressing sets or set theory in UML (possibly by composite model)

Tags: uml, set, composite, set-theory

If we define a **boundary is an area in space**
and a **location is a point in space**
..and a location is attached one boundary
and **we maintain a boundary structure**
..where any **boundary can have one or more "parents/owners"**
..and any **boundary can have zero or more "children"**
..and the boundary structure has a root boundary 
..and the boundary structure terminated by many boundary leaves

then...

Given boundary 2 is owned by boundary 1
..and location A is attached to boundary 1
When I attach location A to a boundary 2
Then the location A is detached to boundary 1
..and location A is attached to boundary 2

likewise, vice versa...

Given boundary 4 is owned by boundary 3
..and location B is attached to boundary 4
When I attach location B to a boundary 3
Then the location B is detached to boundary 4
..and location B is attached to boundary 3

but

Given boundary 7 is owned by boundaries 5 and 6 (i.e. shared)
..and location C is associated to boundary 7
When I attempt to attach location C to either boundary 5 or 6
Then the attempt will not be successfull

**Question: Is there a way of succinctly expressing all of this through a UML class diagram?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not only a UML class diagram, but...

`If we define a boundary is an area in space
and a location is a point in space ...`
This paragraph describes the entities and their relationships. You can model that with a class diagram.

`Given boundary 4 is owned by boundary 3...` and `Given boundary 4 is owned by boundary 3...` These paragraphs describe objects and their associations. You can describe that with a object diagrams. Obviously, the relationships between the objects in these two object diagrams should conform to the relationships of the classes presented in the class diagram.

`Given boundary 7 is owned by boundaries 5 and 6 (i.e. shared)...` You can describe this as well with an object diagram.

`When I attempt to attach location C to either boundary 5 or 6 Then the attempt will not be successful`. Obviously, trying to change the object associations like that would produce an object diagram that violates the relationships defined in the class diagram.

This what this (obviously school exercise) is about, drawing a class diagram that visualizes the relationships between classes and some object diagrams that visualize the associations between specific instances of these classes.

Comment: OK, it looked like an school excercise. I suggest you include also the sub-types of boundary (city, town etc) in your class diagram.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to take your "school exercise" comment, but thanks for your comment nonetheless. My problem is an actual application development issue. I take your comment about adding an object diagram to my work but isn't it obsolete (i.e. not defined in UML 2.4 and it was last defined in UML 1.4.2)?

Comment: Your description looked more theoretical that an actual problem, this is why I thought it is a school exercise. I didn't mean something bad. In your problem description I see relationships between specific object instances. This is why I think that you need object diagrams. This is what they are meant for. In http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html, I can see object diagrams included in UML 2.5, but I wouldn't bother even if it had been removed by any version of UML. UML is necessary in order to visualize the solution to a problem. If an object diagram helps you do the work, why care?

Comment: I take your point: why care? I was expecting another model diagram that replaces it, and if so then I work with that instead. Anyway, thanks for replying, it was useful.